# custom fonts in xcode 7 and adaptive layout

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, storyboard, autolayout

So I'm running into a problem with custom fonts using Xcode 7 with adaptive layout. It's kind of strange. Basically, the custom fonts appear in the storyboards and preview but do not display on the actual devices when I run the app.

i have this problem just with custom fonts, I have the fonts correctly installed. That is not the problem. I have checked that repeatedly. The font shows up in the label's attributes inspector. I select the font from the list of custom fonts from the attributes inspector. The font appears in the storyboard. But when I run... no custom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem with building a custom UI Elements

```
@IBDesignable class ExUITextField: UITextField {

@IBInspectable var fontName: String = "yourCustomFont" {
    didSet {
        self.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size:self.font!.pointSize)
    }
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size:self.font!.pointSize)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that fonts are properly added in the Xcode project and include them in Info.plist file.

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>Colaborate-Bold.otf</string>
    <string>SourceSansPro-Regular.otf</string>
    <string>SourceSansPro-Semibold.otf</string>
</array>
```

[image]

Here is the link about Common Mistakes with Custom Fonts:

http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your fonts aren't being bundled with your app. You've already ensured that the fonts are installed in your *project*, but you also have to make sure that they're among the *resources* that are included for your build target.

Comment: these are my bundle resource and info.plist files in my project,,,

Comment: [Screen_Shot_2015-10-26_at_8.31.58_AM.png](http://fs2.filegir.com/the%20end/Screen_Shot_2015-10-26_at_8.31.58_AM.png) and [Screen_Shot_2015-10-26_at_8.32.20_AM.png](http://fs2.filegir.com/the%20end/Screen_Shot_2015-10-26_at_8.32.20_AM.png) i double checked them,,